# Why do I get a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, android

I am getting a `ClassCastException` on running this simple application.

I'm trying to use the `AlarmManager` for the first time.

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       try {
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
         Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();

        }
     }

    }
```

this is my manisfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.tcs.mine"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
         <activity android:name=".AlarmReciever"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the stack trace too. By the way, you are nowhere checking your objects for null values (would not hurt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AlarmReceiver` is not an `Activity` but declared as one. Check the documentation on [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and [how to declare them in the manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html). Maybe you want to check [this tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Comment: well thanx for the correction but still i am not able to see the message  i am trying to print...

Comment: Well... your question was why you get a `ClassCastException`. As you probably have changed at least the manifest file, you should probably update your question with the appropriate information (or open a new one). Also you should check whether the `onReceive()` method is being called at all. In case it isn't have you read the links a linked? Have you added an `<intent-filter>` definition on your `<receiver>` tag like it is described there?

Comment: thnx Stephan....for the information..i did all the changes required and now the code is running well. :)

Answer (score 0):

The package statement is missing at the top of your java class.

Besides, check how the AlarmReceiver is spelled throughout your .java and .xml files. Somewhere is called AlarmReciever.